# Apache2 - Error: 403 after installation of RewriteEngine

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have to following problem. After installing RewriteEngine on my Apache server by `sudo a2enmode rewrite && service-apache restart` I am getting a 403 Permission Error, when trying to access the Website. The error log reads:

```
[Mon Aug 03 16:47:04.772033 2015] [authz_core:error] [pid 27107] [client ::1:41610] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /home/lenxn/Venuzle/vvm/public/
```

The access log:

```
::1 - - [03/Aug/2015:17:08:11 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 2267 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0 Iceweasel/31.8.0"
```

The `apache2.conf` remained unaffected from the installation and the `.htaccess` in my source root directory looks like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule .* https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

What is the problem here? I have been able to access the server previous to the installation. Have there been any files created or alternated, which overrule my previous permission settings?

Answer (score 0):

I finally fixed it by altering the section

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
</Directory>
```

from the `apache2.conf` to

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory> .
```